# Git Storage with Private & Public branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to set up a repository (either bitbucket / github / ... ) where I can have a private Git repo for developers but also a public access to releases. Which service provides that?
On Sourceforge everything is public, seems in Bitbucket everying is either all private or all public.

Which service do you recommend?

Comment: For releases you simply mean downloads? Or public access to the repository that is always "up to date" to the last public release?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your goal, but it doesn't make much sense. Once you merge your private branch into public every single commit in the private branch up to the new tip will inevitably become public. If you just wan't to maintain privacy before you release, you can have the "everything either all private or all public" and only push your private branch to that repository.

Answer (score 1):

Github provides public repos for free and private ones for a reasonable cost.  You can determine when you create the repo whether it's public or private.

There is no limit to the public repos on an account, but private ones cost an increasing amount as you add them.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up two different remote repos if you do not want to pay anything for a private repo in github.

The private one on a personal server with [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) or [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and the public one on github / bitbucket.

The release branch will have the github / bitbucket as remote repo:

```
git remote add release github:user/repo
```

The development branch with private acces:

```
git remote add develop server:/path/to/repo
```

To push to a specific remote branch just type

```
git push release / develop
```